# Is cement board that's been stored in the weather ok to use?

Tags: shower, installation

The previous owner of my home told me that the cement board he was going to use for a shower has been sitting outside (exposed to the weather) for about a year. The 4x8 sheets are still intact but seem to be less rigid than new cement board. Can I still use it?

I'm in Florida, so it would just be rain, heat, the sheets are sun bleached but intact. When I installed a sheet I noticed that there is a "slight give" between the studs so it is not as ridged as a new sheet. The tiles are big - 18X26 inches which will still make the wall solid and since the board is in good shape otherwise so the tiles will stick.

Comment: How much are new sheets? How much is your time worth to do the job twice? Which option do you prefer?

Comment: Storage not as specified, but may just be the "fine microcracking". Anyway, this should be the thing to consult: https://www.usg.com/content/dam/USG_Marketing_Communications/united_states/product_promotional_materials/finished_assets/usg-durock-cement-board-with-edgeguard-submittal-en-CB399EG.pdf

Comment: Living in Oregon I can’t tell you how many times mine got soaked on the way to the job, I would be concerned if it was wet and then froze or was left in direct sunlight for a year will that affect the mesh? Maybe the top sheet is?

Comment: Yes, the freezing is key. I wouldn't use product that's been frozen repeatedly. It's probably badly degraded. Please revise to add more information about that.

Comment: Make sure you apply a waterproofing membrane before the tiles go on (e.g. redgard). You should anyway, but some people use a primer instead. All the more important if the boards are micro-cracked from the weather.